# Android libgdx - check if touched on image

Tags: android, io, libgdx, textures

I am trying to create a simple android game using libgdx. I have image in screen and I need to identify if I touched on the image. Following is the code I wrote so far.

```
public final static float VP_WIDTH = 480 * INV_SCALE;
public final static float VP_HEIGHT = 800 * INV_SCALE;

private OrthographicCamera camera;
private ExtendViewport viewport;
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture texture;
private int screenHeight, screenWidth;
Sprite playImage;

@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    // pick a viewport that suits your thing, ExtendViewport is a good start
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(VP_WIDTH, VP_HEIGHT, camera);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        texture = new Texture("play.png");
        playImage = new Sprite(texture);
        playImage.setSize(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
}

public void render() {

    camera.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(playImage, 240 - texture.getWidth() / 2, 200 - texture
                .getHeight() / 2);
    batch.end();

}

public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    texture.dispose();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
}

public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    camera.unproject(tp.set(screenX, screenY, 0));
    if (state.equals(States.STARTED)) {
        if (screenX >= screenWidth / 2 - texture.getWidth() / 2 && screenX <= screenWidth / 2 + texture
                .getWidth() / 2 && screenY <= 3 * screenHeight / 4 + texture.getHeight() / 2 && screenY
                >= 3 * screenHeight / 4 - texture.getHeight() / 2)
            playButtonClicked = true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

In the screen I see my image positioned properly, but when I click it, it only goes in to the for loop when I click on the middle part of the image.

It seems like screenX and screenY are ranging from something different than 480,800. Can someone point me if I am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you unproject with the camera, the unprojected x and y are contained in the `tp` vector you used. Java methods cannot modify the values of passed-in parameters (like can be done with pointers in C).

Other than that, your code looks highly un-maintainable. You are drawing the image with one set of equations and calculating its touch boundary with a different set of complicated equations. You should define its boundary in one place (maybe a Rectangle member variable) and use that both for drawing and hit detection.